# ~/.bash_profile not updating python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, bash

I am trying to install python3 via homebrew which I have done successfully. The set of instructions that I am following then suggests to update my

```
'PATH'
```

in

```
~/.bash_profile
```

I didn't have a file under that name so I created one using TextEditor. The next set of instructions then prompts me to enter the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I have no idea what this line of code means but when I type "echo $PATH" in my terminal it gives me back the following line:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But the python files that I am trying to point to and work in are located in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_2
```

So now when I try to reload my ~/.bash_profile to see if anything has changed, nothing appears in the file. 
My main problem that I believe is happening is that my terminal keeps pointing to python files that I do not want to be working in. If anyone has helpful insight as to how I can resolve this problem I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: when  you run program (for example in terminal) then system use folders from PATH to find this program. `PATH=/../:$PATH` means "get value from $PATH, add folder /.../ at the beginning and assign everything again to PATH". You can use `which python` to get full path to python used as default.

Comment: @furas so I finally got PATH to mimic what I want it to but now my ~/.bash_profile file hasn't changed when I check on it. So I manually changed the path in my file and when I try to source it this error is popping out: -bash: /Users/Perez/.bash_profile: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /Users/Perez/.bash_profile: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
any insight on that?

Comment: it looks strange. Maybe show all file. Maybe you use some special char or you forgot to close quotation.